# Disable automatic cleaning of temporary directories in py.test

Tags: pytest, temporary-directory

Running py.test creates tempory repositories to help us save reports,data,outputs,.. etc

They can be found at `DRIVE:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pytest-of-USERNAME\`

Like stated in the documentation on p.72:

> Temporary directories are by default created as sub-directories of the
>   system temporary directory. The base name will be pytest-NUM where NUM
>   will be incremented with each test run. Moreover, entries older than 3
>   temporary directories will be removed.

As I run multiple tests, the maximum of 3 temporary directories is very annoying, is there a way to change this value?

Answer (score 2):

Since these are temporary directories, you can not rely on them to stay. The name says it all. Running py.test on Unix, the tmp directories are actually stored in the /tmp directory, which is emptied on every system restart.

You should instead move your content somewhere safe. This could be done by using a yield fixture to create a temporary directory and then, in tear down phase copy the contents of the directory to a safe place.

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="session")
def my_tmp_dir(tmpdir_factory):
   t = tmpdir_factory.mktemp('some_test_path')
   yield t
   # do things to copy away your tmp directory
   # to a safe place.
```

Comment: The problem isn't the files are deleted, but that it is after 3 runs only..
The solution you gave is already the workaround i used.. but is not satisfying.